# i want to make a loop, for every x actions do y

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I want to make a loop, to run x times, and when it has run x times, then do y and start again to run x time like first time.

This is what Itried, but run only 1 time (x), and then did (y) but I need to run 20 times (x) and only after 20 times do y and start again to do (x)

```
                    for user in usernames:
                    print('Sending Commnet!...')
                    
                        try:
                            time.sleep(1)
                            driver.find_element(
                                By.XPATH, comment_section).send_keys(f'@{user} ')
                            time.sleep(1)
                            mentiune = mentiune + 1
                            if f'@{user}' in driver.page_source:
                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                print(
                                    f'{Fore.GREEN} {user} --> Added to comment Successfuly! -- {datetime.now()}  -- {Fore.RESET} \n')
                                x = random.randint(0.5, 1)
                                print(f'{str(x)} secound sleeped!... \n')
                                time.sleep(x)
                            else:
                                print(f'{username} is Reaport')
                                continue
                                
                        except:
                            pass
                        
                    
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, send_button).click()
```

So, i need, to get from "usernames" line by line "user" and type in a comment "@+user " 20 times, and then click "send_button" and then type again 20 users, but not from the start of the list.

---

I inserted [the full code here](https://pastebin.com/dc0NPat7)

Comment: You may want to look at generators. They allow you to get one element at a time but remember where you were and get the next element with the yield keyword (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-yield-keyword/)

Comment: No, i have a file.txt with usernames, so, i want that the script, to get from file.txt, row by row one username and insert it in comment box, and when it inserted 20 usernames, execute an click on send_button and then insert next 20 usernames and again click on send_button until no more usernames in file.txt

Comment: Can you please include a simplified version of your code that makes your problem very clear. There is a lot going on there

Comment: @Sheena i inserted full code

Comment: Did my answer work? Are you still having trouble with something?

Comment: Less code would be better than more code. If you zoom in on the actual problem then it would be easier to solve. And the solution would be more useful to more people

Comment: I know, but  im not a such good programmer, and im creating how i can, now im not focusing on the speed of working, im focusing to make it work how i want. If u can help me to solve this queestion please.

Comment: @yagod i dont know how to use your part of code, sorry.
I inserted the full code in my question, if u can help me to make it work based on my entire code.

Comment: What part of my code is unclear for you, maybe I can help you understand? I think if you know what you want to do with the user and you know what you want to do once you have collected 20 of them, it's pretty straightforward, you just have to paste those thing where I have left the comments "# do something with user" and "# do y". But you need to understand that this site is to get an answer to a specific question, not to have other people rewrite your entire code.

Comment: @yagod ok, i will try tomorrow and i will come with an answer

Comment: If you tried my code earlier and it didn't work, it's cause I had a syntax error, the yield keyword doesn't use parentheses, I corrected it now.

Comment: @yagod i tried your code, really, i did't was able to run successfully your code, im not smart enought, to make it to work (

Comment: Can you edit the post to show what you tried and what the error message was?

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```py
def generator(usernames):
    for user in usernames:
        yield user

def my_func(usernames):
    generator_obj = generator(usernames)
    try:
        while True:
            for _ in range(20):
                user = next(generator_obj)
                # do something with user
            # do y
    except StopIteration:
        # do y again for last few items
        return None
```